# Detecting if a bootstrap navbar is collapsed or not in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `navbar` inside a its own component called `menu`. I created a service, to be able to detect later on from other components if the navbar is collapsed or not. So anytime from other components I can refer to the service and determine if the navbar is collapsed.

The navbar is not collapsed if it has the class `show`.

So I can refer to the navbar in the menu component:

```
@ViewChild("navbar") navbar: ElementRef;
```

And I can check if it is collapsed or not using:

```
this.navbar.nativeElement.classList.contains("show")
```

How can I detect from inside the service if the navbar is collapsed?

Here is a running code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyquht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a Subject with Boolean value in service.
Triggering next for each update of menu expand and collapse
please go through the updated stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l7hw7p